# What is getFileFormat() Method in Lotus Notes Java API and what is the value it returns?

Tags: lotus-notes

I was created a program in java for getting nsf file Details. I have passed the filepath which contains the nsf file for getting database. I want to know about the getFileFormat() method and what is the value it returns.

```
Database db = session.getDatabase("", filePath);
System.out.println("File Format :"+db.getFileFormat());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will get the format version of the database.  Essentially the version from which the database was created. It's equivalent to this method:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc%2Fr_domino_Database_FileFormat.html

Comment: Thank you Ken... One of the NSF File Which I have returns the value of 16 for getFileFormat() method... Could you please tell in which version the database is created?

Comment: It's very old - Notes 1.x or Notes 2.x.  More here:  http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Notes_Storage_Facility_(NSF)